# Blender Python: Can't open Font on Windows

Tags: scripting, text-object

I have been troubles setting up my default font in my script. I have tried , `bpy.ops.font.open(filepath="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\comic.ttf")`, but the result font is another one.

Does someone know the path?

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct path on Windows, but Python require uses backslash ('\') as a special character, so you can either write the string as `r"C:\Windows\Fonts\comic.ttf"` or as `C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\comic.ttf`.  That is, you can either use the `r` prefix to tell Python to not use backslash as a special character or you can "escape" the backslash by typing it twice wherever you want it once.